# Floats not working, Second Background Image not registering as a background, Centering things?

Tags: html, css, css-float, positioning, clearfix

So to start off let me just note that I am not tech savy at all. I find most computers difficult and I wouldn't be taking this class unless I needed it to graduate from my university.

I'm trying to make a webpage for class thats due tomorrow and I am struggling to get all my stuff positioned properly. I made a mock up design in photoshop for what I'm trying to achieve but actually implementing it has been beyond fustrating.

Most floats aren't working(Probably my fault since I'm struggling to understand the concept).

I also made a secondary background image but its registering as a normal one I think.

Also is there a string of code I can use to center everyting like it is in my mock up?

[How its suppose to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9xwY.jpg)

[How mine looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7UWg.png)

My code:

```css
/*The Main Background*/
body {
     background-image: url(../img/background.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
} 

#HeaderImage{
    background-image: url(../img/HeaderImage.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
     z-index: 1;
     background-position: left; 


}

.container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Nav Element */

/*The Search Bar */form div{
/*Margin Header */ 48px;
float:left;
}


.site-navigation {
    height: 155px;
}

.site-navigation img {
    margin-top: 16px;
    float:left;
}

.site-navigation ul {
    width: 490px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.site-navigation li {
    margin: 35px 33px;
    float: left;
}

.site-navigation a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.site-navigation a:hover {
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

/* Header Element */

h2 {
    line-height: 0.8;
    font-size: 72px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    width: 450px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 115px;
    padding-bottom: 42px;
}

.search{

}

.SearchGlass{
    float: left;
    position: top;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container"></div>
        <header class="Team Sky">
            <nav class="site-navigation">
                <img src="img/TeamSkyLogo.png" alt="Team Sky Logo">
                 <ul class="clearfix">
                    <li><a href="#">shop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">checkout</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">video</a></li>
                </ul>

                <!-- SEARCH BAR AND MAGNIFYING GLASS!--> 


                  <div class="SearchGlass" id="SearchGlass">
                  <img src="img/magnifyingglass.png" alt="Magnifying Glass">
                  </div>


                     <form>
                     <div class="search"> 
                        <!-- don't need a label here - use placeholder="" (see forms we did in class - it's on moodle -->
                        <label for="search">search</label> 
                        <input id="search" type="text" name="search"/>

                    </div>
                </form>

                </nav>




                <div id="HeaderImage">
        <img src="img/HeaderImage.png" alt="Dude on a bike"> 
    </div>

                    <!-- need to close your form element -->    

            <div class="TeamSkylogo">
            <h2>Team Sky</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="RoadToYellow">
            <P>the road to yellow</P>
            </div>
             <!--Shop Team Sky-->


        <main>

        <h1> TEAM NEWS </h1>
        <!-- each article/blog should be in it's own container -->
        <div class="articleone">
        <img src="img/ArticleImageOne.png" alt="Water"> 
        <h1>Giro d'Italia</h1>
        <P>Landa will lead the team on the back of his assured and impressive win at the giro del Trentino, and he returns to the race having excelled last year, when he won</P>

        <!--readon !-->
        </div>

        <div class="articletwo">
        <img src="img/ArticleImageTwo.png" alt="Bikes by River">
        <h1>Krudder Gets a Break</h1>
        <P>The powerful German who was a rock in the beginning of the season will now get a break from and is expected to return for the Malecour at the end of the season</P>
        <!--readon !-->
        </div>

        <div>
        <img src="img/ArticleImageThree.png" alt="Bike Dudes Biking">
        <h1>Kinnick's New Contract</h1>
        <P>Peter Kinnick contract is still not settled with the team manager Alistar McDowell saying that a new contract offer has been made</P>
        <!--readon !-->
        </div>

        <div class="articlefour">
        <img src="img/ArticleImageFour.png" alt="Single Guy On Bike">
        <h1>Froom In Third</h1>
        <P>Chris Froom Finished Third in the opening prologue stage at the Criterium du Dauphine with a strong showing on the first day</P>
        <!--readon !-->
        </div>
    </main>

<footer>
    <img src="img/sponsor1.png" alt="Team Sky Sponsor">
   <img src="img/sponsor2.png" alt="Pinarello">
    <img src="img/sponsor3.png" alt="Shimano">
     <img src="img/sponsor4.png" alt="Rayha">
      <img src="img/sponsor5.png" alt="21ST Century Fox">
    </footer>
```

THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP

Comment: Can you please use snippets? (`<>`)

Comment: Yeah sorry just trying to figure out how to do a snippet. As I said I'm not very technology savy sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, but there are lot of issues in the above given code,hope you can get it correct , try this code for now

```css
body {
     background-image: url(../img/background.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#HeaderImage{
    background-image: url(../img/HeaderImage.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
     z-index: 1;
     background-position: left;


}

.container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Nav Element */

/*The Search Bar */form div{
/*Margin Header */ 48px;
float:left;
}


.site-navigation {
    height: 155px;
}

.site-navigation img {
    margin-top: 16px;
    float:left;
}

.site-navigation ul {
    width: 490px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.site-navigation li {
    margin: 35px 33px;
    float: left;
}

.site-navigation a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.site-navigation a:hover {
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

/* Header Element */

h2 {
    line-height: 0.8;
    font-size: 72px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    width: 450px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 115px;
    padding-bottom: 42px;
}

.search{

}

.SearchGlass{
    float: left;
    position: top;
}
.article{
  float: left;width: 100%;margin-bottom: 15px
}
.article img {float: left;width: 28%;margin-right: 1%}
.article h1{float:left;width: 70%;margin: 5px 0;text-align: left;}
.article p{float:left;width: 70%;margin: 5px 0;text-align: left;}
h1{text-align: left;}
footer{display: block;width: 100%;float: left;}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
          <header class="Team Sky">
              <nav class="site-navigation">
                  <img src="img/TeamSkyLogo.png" alt="Team Sky Logo">
                   <ul class="clearfix">
                      <li><a href="#">shop</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">checkout</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">video</a></li>
                  </ul>

                  <!-- SEARCH BAR AND MAGNIFYING GLASS!-->


                    <div class="SearchGlass" id="SearchGlass">
                    <img src="img/magnifyingglass.png" alt="Magnifying Glass">
                    </div>


                       <form>
                       <div class="search">
                          <!-- don't need a label here - use placeholder="" (see forms we did in class - it's on moodle -->
                          <label for="search">search</label>
                          <input id="search" type="text" name="search"/>

                      </div>
                  </form>

                  </nav>




                  <div id="HeaderImage">
          <img src="img/HeaderImage.png" alt="Dude on a bike">
      </div>

                      <!-- need to close your form element -->

              <div class="TeamSkylogo">
              <h2>Team Sky</h2>
              </div>

              <div class="RoadToYellow">
              <P>the road to yellow</P>
              </div>
               <!--Shop Team Sky-->


          <div>

          <h1> TEAM NEWS </h1>
          <!-- each article/blog should be in it's own container -->
          <div class="article">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x500" alt="Water">
          <h1>Giro d'Italia</h1>
          <P>Landa will lead the team on the back of his assured and impressive win at the giro del Trentino, and he returns to the race having excelled last year, when he won</P>

          <!--readon !-->
          </div>

          <div class="article">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x500" alt="Water">
          <h1>Giro d'Italia</h1>
          <P>Landa will lead the team on the back of his assured and impressive win at the giro del Trentino, and he returns to the race having excelled last year, when he won</P>

          <!--readon !-->
          </div>





      </div>

  <footer>
      <img src="img/sponsor1.png" alt="Team Sky Sponsor">
     <img src="img/sponsor2.png" alt="Pinarello">
      <img src="img/sponsor3.png" alt="Shimano">
       <img src="img/sponsor4.png" alt="Rayha">
        <img src="img/sponsor5.png" alt="21ST Century Fox">
      </footer>

      </div>
```

Comment: This is really helpful to look at. Again sorry my code is sloppy I'm not the best at this sorta thing and thank you again for helping me out a little bit.

Comment: hope it will be helpful,  use only one class *article* and change the css according to your requirement